Support Requested: Updating Microsoft Office 2019 Home & Business on an Offline Server
We are currently using Windows Server 2019 with Microsoft Office 2019 Home & Business installed. Our server does not have internet connectivity, and we need to update Microsoft Office 2019 Home & Business to address several CVEs.
We have Microsoft Office 2019 Home & Business version 16.0.16130.20332 installed and need to update to version 16.0.17231.20236 or the latest version.
I have already tried using the Office Deployment Tool and Office Customization Tool to download the updates, but these tools only list Office Professional Plus 2019 and Office Standard 2019, with no option to download Microsoft Office 2019 Home & Business.
Due to cybersecurity policies, we cannot connect any machines within the organization to the internet. We need to download the latest Microsoft Office 2019 Home & Business updates on an online machine (outside the organization), transfer the update file to the server, and then install the updates.
Any alternative methods or specific troubleshooting steps to achieve this would be very helpful.

The only solution I can suggest is you connect the machine to the internet, before any business data is accessed, install Office 2019 then create a Windows image from the system after you take it offline. Alternatively, you can use the exact same method you used to install Office 2019 (16.0.16130.20332) originally

Use ODT (Setup.exe) tool and .xml file to download the updates files and copy to your local shared folder. Use ODT to change the update path of your Office 2019, then you may update Office 2019 from your local source. But please note, this will increase a lot of labor costs.

Thank you for your valuable response. I used the methods outlined in the following links to update Office 2019 offline using the Office CDN method:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ltsc/2021/deploy                                                    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/troubleshoot/installation/product-ids-supported-office-deployment-click-to-run
